# Hazelcast Executor - Can we find the queue tasks that are pending

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast with Executor framework. I am submitting jobs into the Hazelcast queue and I want to throttle it. I am not able to get the Queue size of the pending tasks.

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no direct api for that. But you can set the queueCapacity on the executor using the configuration of the executor and you will get an RejectedExecutionException when the queue is full, so that might be a solution.

Do you want to know the queue size in total or for a member? Because each member will have a queue containing tasks to process and they can all have completely different sizes.

Anyhow, once you can retrieve the queue size for a member, you can can easily do it for the full cluster.

Comment: I want the queue size of individual members. I am already setting the queue size but I am doing throttling so that I dont flood the queue with tasks.

Comment: I would go through the DistributedExecutorService (the main service that manages all the executors) and load your ManagedExecutorService. It does have methods for determining the number of items on the queue.